# What is big O notation of these permutation algorithms

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, runtime, big-o

Working my way through "Cracking the coding interview", and a practice question says

> Given 2 strings, write a method to decide if one is a permutation of the other.

The author's python solution is as follows:

```
def check_permutation(str1, str2):
    if len(str1) != len(str2):
        return False
    counter = Counter()
    for c in str1:
        counter[c] += 1
    for c in str2:
        if counter[c] == 0:
            return False
        counter[c] -= 1
    return True
```

Which claims to be in O(N) time.

My solution is as follows:

```
def perm(str1,str2):
    if(len(str1) != len(str2)):
        return False
    for c in str1:
        if c not in Str2:
            return False
    return True
```

And I believe this to also be O(N). Is this true?  Which algorithm is favorable? The author's data type seems unneccesary.

And lastly, is this algorithm O(NlogN)?

```
def perm(str1,str2):
    return sorted(str1)==sorted(str2)
```

Comment: Couldn't the author's code be simplified like this: `return Counter(str1) == Counter(str2)`?

Comment: Your function returns true for `perm("ABB", "BAA")`, which are not permutations of each other. The author's solution _counts_ occurrences of characters.

Comment: Yea, your code doesn't handle repeats well at all

Comment: You could make a `O(nlogn)` solution easily if you sorted both strings then checked for equality at each index

Comment: I see now the flaw in mine, thanks @khelwood .  Would the 3rd algorithm work?

Comment: That seems as if it would work, but @G_M what makes that different than the 3rd option I presented?

Comment: @Jeff Same result I guess but no sorting involved, less time complexity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the author's solution is an optimized version of `Counter(str1) == Counter(str2)` (it returns `False` faster and creates a single instance of a `Counter`).
It is, indeed, `O(n)` because hash table (`Counter`) access is `O(1)`.

Next, your solution is *quadratic* (`O(n^2)`) because each `in` is `O(n)` - it has to traverse the whole string.
It is also wrong on strings with repetitions.

Third, `sorted(str1) == sorted(str2)` is, indeed, linearithmic (`O(n*log(n))`)
and thus is worse than the original linear solution.

Note, however, that for *small* strings the constants may make a
difference and the linearithmic (`sorted`) solution may turn out to be
*faster* than the linear (`Counter`) one.

Finally, beware that Python is usually implemented using an interpreter, so the actual performance may depend on whether you are using features implemented in C or in Python. E.g., if `Counter` is implemented in C, then `Counter(str1) == Counter(str2)` will probably outperform the author's solution hands down, even though *algorithmically* the author's solution is better.

Answer (score 0):

For the first code, it could be easy by using `collection.Counter` instead of loops:

```
def check_permutation(str1, str2):
    if len(str1) != len(str2):
        return False
    return Counter(str1) == Counter(str2)
```

And it is `O(n)` again. The last algorihtm, as there is a sorting and using `sorted` it is `O(nlogn)`.

Your algorithm is not true as you find a character inside the other string without concern of the number of the repetition of that character. If it was true, it would be `O(n^2)`.

Therefore, in a general sence,  the first algorithm has the best time complexity and easy to be implemented.